# GLSurfaceView scrollTo does nothing

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I've been trying for a while to vertically scroll a GLSurfaceView that's not displayed in its entirety. I feel a bit dumb posting such a short explanation of my question, but that's all I can muster: I know the window is getting the click and drag events, but scrollTo (100% sure it gets correct parameters) does not move the window at all.

EDIT: After a bit more tweaking, I found methods for manipulating the surface through the GL10 gl object, but it is completely unresponsive. It doesn't bother to act on the simplest of tasks, like setting the surface to a single color with glClearColor(). onDrawFrame() of the renderer is getting called, but calling functions on the gl objects (or static functions from the GLES10 class) does nothing, what could possibly cause this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you want to scroll the contents of a GLSurfaceView, update the view transformation matrix.  If you want to move the entire Surface around it may look a bit weird.

Comment: How can I apply a matrix to it? Code already has a matrix that handles the changes for the bitmap surface, but I didn't find a way to apply it to the OpenGL surface.

Comment: Are you using GLES 1 or 2?  How are you configuring your model/view/projection matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For closure's sake, a possible reason for a GL10 object not to respond is that it might have been passed by value to onDrawFrame(), and not by reference.